# Powershell is always opening "As Administrator"

Tags: powershell

Whenever I open Powershell or Powershell ISE it is defaulting to open as administrator. I'm not using a shortcut icon on my desktop, but simply the default apps from the start menu. As a test I went straight to the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 folder and opened powershell.exe from there and it is doing the same thing.

Any idea how this would be defaulting so that it is always launching this way? Its nice sometimes to not have to remember but ideally its only running with elevated privileges if I specify that.

If it helps I'm running Windows 10 release 1809

Comment: See the accepted answer here, and see if that resolves it.  Sounds like you need to disable the "Run as Administrator" option on the executables... but keep in mind if you have any disk/OS dependent stepsin your code, then *not being an administrative privileged account could be an issue.*   [SuperUser Link](https://superuser.com/questions/547810/how-to-turn-off-always-run-as-administrator-windows-8-10)

Comment: As far as i know there is no way to check or uncheck that box directly on the exe. I've only seen that option on the shortcuts to a program.

I understand it will remove running with elevated privileges, but I don't need that access all the time and I'd rather be safe and not have it unless I explicitly want it.

Comment: You aren't looking at shortcuts, you're looking at the OS configuration for that executable.  Those weren't shortcuts being modified, they were configurations for how to handle that application specifically and uniquely.

Comment: There is no compatibility tab for 64-bit executables, like the Powershell file, nor is there a "troubleshoot compatibility" item in the context menu in Windows 10.